# Using python ctype, an error occurred when matching the type of the pointer array and the array, which is an argument of a C library function

Tags: python, c, dll, md5, ctypes

The following error occurred while checking whether the hash generated by Python on the PC and the hash generated by the board match with the md5.c file of the embedded board I am using.

TypeError: byref() argument must be a ctypes instance, not 'list'
OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x033D2000

```
import os
from ctypes import *
import subprocess

class MD5_CTX(Structure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [("i", c_int * 2),
                ("buf", c_int * 4),
                ("in", c_short * 64),
                ("digest", c_short * 16)]
current_machine_id = subprocess.check_output('wmic csproduct get uuid').decode().split('\n')[1].strip()

current_machine_id = current_machine_id.replace('-','')
print(current_machine_id)

Hash = create_string_buffer(16)

Init_read_byte = CDLL('md5lib').MD5Init
Init_read_byte.argtypes = [POINTER(MD5_CTX)]

Update_read_byte = CDLL('md5lib').MD5Update
Update_read_byte.argtypes = [POINTER(MD5_CTX),POINTER(c_short),c_int]

Final_read_byte = CDLL('md5lib').MD5Update
Final_read_byte.argtypes = [c_char_p, POINTER(MD5_CTX)]

context = MD5_CTX()
Init_read_byte(byref(context))
#Update_read_byte(byref(context), byref(current_machine_id), 16)  !! First Error
Final_read_byte(Hash, byref(context))      !! Second Error

print(sizeof(Hash), repr(Hash.raw))
```

The resulting values are as follows:

```
123456789ABCDEF123456789ABCDEFFF (example)
First Error : TypeError: byref() argument must be a ctypes instance, not 'str'
Second Error : OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x03BB1000
```

The following is the md5.c file's functions.

```
typedef unsigned int u32_t;
/* Data structure for MD5 (Message-Digest) computation */
typedef struct
{
    u32_t i[2];               /* number of _bits_ handled mod 2^64 */
    u32_t buf[4];             /* scratch buffer */
    unsigned short in[64];     /* input buffer */
    unsigned short digest[16]; /* actual digest after MD5Final call */
}MD5_CTX;

__declspec(dllexport) void
MD5Init(MD5_CTX *mdContext)
{
    mdContext->i[0] = mdContext->i[1] = (u32_t)0;

    /* Load magic initialization constants. */
    mdContext->buf[0] = (u32_t)0x67452301UL;
    mdContext->buf[1] = (u32_t)0xefcdab89UL;
    mdContext->buf[2] = (u32_t)0x98badcfeUL;
    mdContext->buf[3] = (u32_t)0x10325476UL;
}

__declspec(dllexport) void
MD5Update(MD5_CTX *mdContext, unsigned short *inBuf, unsigned short inLen)
{
    u32_t in[16];
    short mdi;
    unsigned short i, ii;

    /* compute number of bytes mod 64 */
    mdi = (short)((mdContext->i[0] >> 3) & 0x3F);

    /* update number of bits */
    if ((mdContext->i[0] + ((u32_t)inLen << 3)) < mdContext->i[0])
    {
        mdContext->i[1]++;
    }
    mdContext->i[0] += ((u32_t)inLen << 3);
    mdContext->i[1] += ((u32_t)inLen >> 29);

    while (inLen--)
    {
        /* add new character to buffer, increment mdi */
        mdContext->in[mdi++] = *inBuf++;

        /* transform if necessary */
        if (mdi == 0x40)
        {
            for (i = 0, ii = 0; i < 16; i++, ii += 4)
            {
                in[i] = (((u32_t)mdContext->in[ii + 3]) << 24) |
                    (((u32_t)mdContext->in[ii + 2]) << 16) |
                    (((u32_t)mdContext->in[ii + 1]) << 8) |
                    ((u32_t)mdContext->in[ii]);
            }
            Transform(mdContext->buf, in);
            mdi = 0;
        }
    }
}

__declspec(dllexport) void 
MD5Final(unsigned short hash[], MD5_CTX *mdContext)
{
    u32_t in[16];
    short mdi;
    unsigned short i, ii;
    unsigned short padLen;

    /* save number of bits */
    in[14] = mdContext->i[0];
    in[15] = mdContext->i[1];

    /* compute number of bytes mod 64 */
    mdi = (short)((mdContext->i[0] >> 3) & 0x3F);

    /* pad out to 56 mod 64 */
    padLen = (mdi < 56) ? (56 - mdi) : (120 - mdi);
    MD5Update(mdContext, PADDING, padLen);

    /* append length in bits and transform */
    for (i = 0, ii = 0; i < 14; i++, ii += 4)
    {
        in[i] = (((u32_t)mdContext->in[ii + 3]) << 24) |
            (((u32_t)mdContext->in[ii + 2]) << 16) |
            (((u32_t)mdContext->in[ii + 1]) << 8) |
            ((u32_t)mdContext->in[ii]);
    }
    Transform(mdContext->buf, in);

    /* store buffer in digest */
    for (i = 0, ii = 0; i < 4; i++, ii += 4)
    {
        mdContext->digest[ii] = (unsigned short)(mdContext->buf[i] & 0xFF);
        mdContext->digest[ii + 1] =
            (unsigned short)((mdContext->buf[i] >> 8) & 0xFF);
        mdContext->digest[ii + 2] =
            (unsigned short)((mdContext->buf[i] >> 16) & 0xFF);
        mdContext->digest[ii + 3] =
            (unsigned short)((mdContext->buf[i] >> 24) & 0xFF);
    }
    memcpy(hash, mdContext->digest, 32);
}
```

What I want to print out in C is as follows.

```
INT8U ID[16] = {0, };
INT8U Hash[16] = {0, };
MD5_CTX context;

MD5Init(&context);
MD5Update(&context, ID, 16); // current machine id instead of ID
MD5Final(Hash, &context);

for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
   printf ("%02x", Hash[i]);
printf("\n");
```

I have been trying to match the parameters of MD5Update and MD5Final, but I was not familiar with python and asked a question.

Thank you if you can help me.

Comment: Please post the full traceback of the error.

Comment: Also bug: `Final_read_byte = CDLL('md5lib').MD5Update` should use `MD5Final`.

Comment: The C code shows `INT8U Hash[16]` but `MD5Final` takes a `unsigned short hash[]`.  This doesn't agree.  Python used a `create_string_buffer(16)` which agrees with the `INT8U` but not the function signature.